# How does google anayltics know about Google ads?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

There is something quite basic that confuses me. I use Google ads conversion tracking with Google Tag Manager, and I don't understand how my google analytics know about these ads in the first place. I mean, the conversion tags I create in Google Tag Manager don't include the Google Analytics tracking code at all.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It knows based on the url structure of the incoming links.

This link gives a good overview.
[UTM Codes: How to Track Campaign URLs in Google Analytics](https://www.hallaminternet.com/setting-campaign-url-tagging-google-analytics/)

This tool allows you to see how the different urls are built and decomposed in GA.
[campaign-url-builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)

Essentially the structure is integrated and google analytics logically decomposes and presents the data in a meaningful format based on URL.